# Identify manufacturer logo

Tags: identification

How do I identify a manufacturer of a DC jack? (from a Clevo laptop). Is there a logo database somewhere?

The part number doesn't yield any hits, Google/Bing image search don't show anything either. All the eBay sellers for 'Clevo dc jack' have the wrong type (same logo but no brand name mentioned).

Straight up answers for the manufacturer name are appreciated, but I'm more looking to learn how to help myself.

[image: Sought after manufacturer logo]

Comment: edit the image so that it is black lines on white background, then use it to do google image search ... you may get a hit

Comment: But if you are looking for a replacement connector, you better not get fixed on the specific manufacturer (which could be very well out of business, or hard to get)